# How to create GeoJSON collection with distinct features?

Tags: javascript, unique, distinct, geojson

Given the following GeoJSON collection:

```json
{
    "type": "FeatureCollection",
    "features": [
        {
            "type": "Feature",
            "geometry": {
                "type": "Point",
                "coordinates": [
                    13.55791,
                    52.54459
                ]
            },
            "properties": {
                "title": "Sommer 2022",
                "opening_hours": null,
            }
        },
        {
            "type": "Feature",
            "geometry": {
                "type": "Point",
                "coordinates": [
                    13.39519,
                    52.5203
                ]
            },
            "properties": {
                "title": "Winter",
                "opening_hours": "Sa,Su,PH 11:00-17:00",
            }
        },
        {
            "type": "Feature",
            "geometry": {
                "type": "Point",
                "coordinates": [
                    13.39519,
                    52.5203
                ]
            },
            "properties": {
                "title": "Winter",
                "opening_hours": "Sa,Su,PH 11:00-17:00",
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

How can I remove duplicate features to finally have a GeoJSON collection with **unique** features?

## Related

- [Extract properties and unique values from GeoJson collection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56993304/extract-properties-and-unique-values-from-geojson-collection)
- [Comparing two complex JSON arrays](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62245387/comparing-two-complex-json-arrays)
- [Javascript | Unique object in Set](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51317553/javascript-unique-object-in-set)
- [Selecting distinct values from a JSON](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17780508/selecting-distinct-values-from-a-json)

Comment: Also related - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1960473/get-all-unique-values-in-a-javascript-array-remove-duplicates

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Checking property by property, assuming they are well-known:

```js
const data = {
  "type": "FeatureCollection",
  "features": [{
      "type": "Feature",
      "geometry": {
        "type": "Point",
        "coordinates": [
          13.55791,
          52.54459
        ]
      },
      "properties": {
        "title": "Sommer 2022",
        "opening_hours": null,
      }
    },
    {
      "type": "Feature",
      "geometry": {
        "type": "Point",
        "coordinates": [
          13.39519,
          52.5203
        ]
      },
      "properties": {
        "title": "Winter",
        "opening_hours": "Sa,Su,PH 11:00-17:00",
      }
    },
    {
      "type": "Feature",
      "geometry": {
        "type": "Point",
        "coordinates": [
          13.39519,
          52.5203
        ]
      },
      "properties": {
        "title": "Winter",
        "opening_hours": "Sa,Su,PH 11:00-17:00",
      }
    }
  ]
}

let resFeat = []

for (let feat of data.features) {
  let filterRes = resFeat.filter(item => item.type == feat.type && item.geometry.type == feat.geometry.type && item.geometry.coordinates[0] == feat.geometry.coordinates[0] && item.geometry.coordinates[1] == feat.geometry.coordinates[1] && item.properties.title == feat.properties.title && item.properties.opening_hours == feat.properties.opening_hours);
  
  if (filterRes.length == 0) {
    resFeat.push(feat)
  }
}

data.features = resFeat

console.log(data)
```